# Using two different LIMIT clauses, do I need to use a UNION statement to return the same data set?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the exact same data set for certain rows in a table, and display it on a paginated part of my website.

I want to get the first row in the `employees` table every query (`LIMIT 1`), but also get a range of rows as dictated by my second `LIMIT` clause. I've been using `UNION ALL` to achieve this, which works even though the query is noticeably slower (~.017s) than the other queries I've used for my website so far. I'm admittedly an SQL novice, so my query also seems repetitive to me.

Is there a better (perhaps faster) way to accomplish this? I would prefer to use a single query if possible.

```
(SELECT employee_name, employee_email, COUNT(reputation_id) as employee_rep
FROM employees
    LEFT JOIN reputation rep
        ON employee_id = rep.employee_id
WHERE employee_title = 'intern'
LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT employee_name, employee_email, COUNT(reputation_id) as employee_rep
FROM employees
    LEFT JOIN reputation rep
        ON employee_id = rep.employee_id
WHERE employee_title = 'intern'
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY employee_date ASC
LIMIT 10, 5)
```

My desired output would be something like this:

- Page 1: First intern is shown, and then display interns 2-10
- Page 2: First intern is shown, and then display interns 11-20

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The first query makes no sense. You are not grouping by anything, so you already only get one row (because you are applying the aggregate function `COUNT`). As you don't specify which employee (`MIN`, `MAX`, whatever), you get an arbitrary pick. `LIMIT 1` is superfluous on this one row of course, but you shouldn't use `LIMIT` without any `ORDER BY` anway, because this too means arbitrarily picking some row. What is this query supposed to do? What do you want to achieve? The second query also suffers from a missing `ORDER BY`. So describe the problem you are trying to address with your query.

Comment: I apologize if I didn't make my question clear enough. What I'm trying to do is display a number of interns per page, but also always display the first intern. On page one, for example, I'd like to display the first intern, and then interns 2-10. On page two, display the first intern, and then interns 11-20. I left out my `ORDER BY` clause and have edited it into my question. The back end of my website dynamically changes the `LIMIT` values on each page.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? This can make a big difference (namely if you are using version 8 already).

Comment: I'm using MariaDB version 10.1.34, though I don't know how this corresponds to a version of MySQL.

Comment: this seems like something best handled in application code

Comment: Ah, okay, this is good. The version doesn't directly correspond. MariaDB is not the same as MySQL (although its root is MySQL, version 5 I think). And how many employees do you expect? If it's just, say, some hundreds only, then I'd simply get all employees from the database and wouldn't bother to filter in SQL, I guess. With some AJAX method you wouldn't even have to access the database again for browsing through the list.

Comment: I'd typically be trying to return less than 200 employees at a time, so I guess I'll get them all, and loop through the data accordingly. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner "For all practical purposes, MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement of the same MySQL version (for example MySQL 5.1 -> MariaDB 5.1, MariaDB 5.2 & MariaDB 5.3 are compatible. MySQL 5.5 is compatible with MariaDB 5.5 and also in practice with MariaDB 10.0, MySQL 5.6 is compatible with MariaDB 10.0 and MySQL 5.7 is compatible with MariaDB 10.2).:"  source https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/ .. But MariaDB has some added features like `CHECK` contraint support en more storage engines stuff like that.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland: I didn't know that. Thank you for the information.